# Creating a Map<String, ArrayList<String[]>> from ArrayList<String[]> in Java

Tags: java, dictionary, collections

I have an ArrayList of String Array and the 2nd element of every String Array contains a name. I want to create a Map where it's Key is the name and Value is an ArrayList of all String Array which has the name.

How can I achive this in Java?

Input: ArrayList<String[]>

```
{"1", "NameABC", "somestring"}
{"2", "NameDEF", "somestring"}
{"3", "NameDEF", "somestring"}
{"4", "NameABC", "somestring"}
{"5", "NameXYZ", "somestring"}
```

Output: Map<String, ArrayList<String[]>

Key = NameABC, Value = ArrayList of String[] where every String[] has NameABC

Key = NameXYZ, Value = ArrayList of String[] where every String[] has NameXYZ

I've tried using `stream.collect(Collectors.toMap())` but I can't figure out how to achieve the proper output.

Comment: Why did you try `stream.collect(Collectors.toMap())`? What was wrong with your attempt?

Comment: I cannot figure out a way to map the 2nd element of the String[]

Comment: By the way, in real work it would likely make more sense to define a [record](https://openjdk.org/jeps/395) to hold the elements of each array as fields in an object. A `record` can be defined locally, within a method.

Answer (score 1):

Streams and collectors are not always the best option:

```
Map<String, List<String[]>> map = new HashMap<>();
myListOfArrays.forEach(arr -> map.computeIfAbsent(arr[1], x -> new ArrayList<>()).add(arr));
```

If the key can be null and you want to store it under a blank, use the expression `arr[1] == null ? "" : arr[1]` instead:

```
myListOfArrays.forEach(arr -> map.computeIfAbsent(arr[1] == null ? "" : arr[1], x -> new ArrayList<>()).add(arr));
```

Comment: Streams are not always the best option, but a stream with `Collectors.groupingBy()` seems perfectly appropriate here.

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
List<String[]> l1 = new ArrayList<>();
    l1.add(new String[]{"1", "NameABC", "somestring"});
    l1.add(new String[]{"2", "NameDEF", "somestring"});
    l1.add(new String[]{"3", "NameDEF", "somestring"});
    l1.add(new String[]{"4", "NameABC", "somestring"});
    l1.add(new String[]{"5", "NameXYZ", "somestring"});
    
    Map<String, List<String[]>> map = l1.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(arr -> arr[1]));
    
    for (Map.Entry<String, List<String[]>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        String key = entry.getKey();
        List<String[]> val = entry.getValue();
        
        System.out.println(key + " -- "+ val);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. Your solution worked. I got an NullPointerException when Key was null but that won't be an issue if I replace null values with empty String.

Comment: What's the point of `new HashMap<>()`? Just assign the stream result straight to your variable. Also, you don't need to work so hard to print a map. Just do `System.out.println(map);`. Otherwise, good answer.

Comment: Or, to get your specific output format, use `map.forEach((key, val) -> System.out.println(key + " -- "+ val));`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Stream` with `groupingBy()`:

```java
public static Map<String, List<String[]>> convert(List<String[]> data) {
    return data.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(arr -> arr[1]));
}
```